# Why did the French not invest much in the stock market prior to 1990?

Tags: stock-market

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_d%27%C3%A9pargne_en_actions says:

> Le PEA a été créé en 1992 afin d'encourager l'investissement en bourse des particuliers, notoirement bas en France.

[Google translation](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=en&text=Le%20PEA%20a%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20cr%C3%A9%C3%A9%20en%201992%20afin%20d%27encourager%20l%27investissement%20en%20bourse%20des%20particuliers%2C%20notoirement%20bas%20en%20France.):

> The PEA was created in 1992 to encourage investment in the stock market [by] individuals, **notoriously low in France**.

Why did the French not invest much in the stock market prior to 1990?

Comment: I don't think there is a definitive answer to this, but I am curious about research on this topic.

Comment: @Bayesian I guess they are some study on how the French managed their finance.